# Is my attempt correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$ such that $\mathrm{E}\left|\xi_{n}\right| \leq 2^{-n} .$ Prove that $\xi_{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely as
$n \rightarrow \infty .$

my attempt : $E |\xi_{n}| \leq 2^{-n}$, therefore by the dominated convergence theorem we have :

$\int_{\Omega} \lim_n |\xi_n| d \mathcal{P} = 0 $

this implies that : $\lim_n |\xi_n| = 0 \text{ a.s. }$

so $\xi_{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely as
$n \rightarrow \infty .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Borel Cantelli lemma. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then by markov's inequality $$P(|\zeta_n|>\varepsilon)\leq \varepsilon^{-1}E|\zeta_n|\le2^{-n} \varepsilon.$$ In particular 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|\zeta_n|>\varepsilon)<\infty
$$
and so $P(|\zeta_n|>\varepsilon \;{\text{i.o}})=0$ and thus $\zeta_n\to 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flaw in your argument,because you assume that the limit of $|\xi_n|$ exists.

Here is what you can do:

By monotone convergence,

$$E(\sum_n|\xi_n|)=\sum_n E(|\xi_n|)<+\infty$$

So $\sum_n|\xi_n|<+\infty$ a.s

Thus $\xi_n \to 0$ a.e